# iTunes refuses to deactivate encryption for backups

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup, encryption

I have an iPhone 5S which I used to backup towards my old MBP. At some point I moved to a new MBP and I realized that I had forgotten my backup encryption password. Obviously there is no point to a password if there is a way around it, so I did what was recommended:

1. take an iCloud backup
2. wipe off the phone
3. remove any existing local backup in iTunes
4. restored the phone from the iCloud backup

So right now there are no local backups, but I still cannot de-activate the encryption, or change the password. I tried Apple ID password, a bunch of other reasonable passwords I might have used. No avail!

I am not trying to decrypt an existing backup, I am merely trying to reset the backup procedure so that I don't have to do my backups on the cloud (also end up paying for storage when I have lots of physical storage at home).

I cannot grasp the motivation behind forever losing a functionality because I cannot remember one of many passwords I have to remember. To add insult to injury Apple homepage won't let me get in touch with support, since my phone is old. However, as far as I can tell the issue is with iTunes, not with the phone.

Some additional info:

- my phone is not jailbroken (thus no ssh access), i'd like to keep it that way if I can
- there's nothing of use in Keychain Access

What can I do?

Comment: You can always get in touch with Apple support - you don't even have to tell them what device you need assistance with until they ring you. I've had them call me, international, to a country that doesn't speak English... in English, to fix an issue with an old iPhone 4 I was giving away to a relative. Their phone support is incomparable. Start at https://support.apple.com/contact?cid=acs::applesearch

Comment: @Tetsujin I dont know if it's an international policy but on the Swedish support page for Apple, it eventually asks me to write in the serial ID before I can setup a phone call. If I enter the serial of the phone, it brings a payment option; if I enter the serial of my MBP then I get an error message where it says "a solution cannot be found" or something like that.

Comment: even if you go via a non-device-specific path, like password/ID issue?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306826/10713